# How to prevent auto lock phone screen in a specific screen react native

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I need to avoid phone from auto locking screen in a specific screen in react native. what is the best way to do that.

Comment: This is not possible. The only other alternative is WAKE LOCK where you prevent the device from sleeping. Ex use case - video playback.

Answer (score 1):

you can used following library for keep screen awake

[click hear](https://reactnativecode.com/react-native-keep-awake/)

[npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-keep-awake)

Answer (score 0):

You can not avoid user locking screen but try using this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-wake-lock this might help.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Also, can you please explain your use case? Maybe there's a better way to achieve what you are trying to do.